# Source of "Nashim Datan Kala"

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, thought

What is the source for "Nashim Datan Kala"?

I know it is applied in rules of Yichud (see Kidushin 80b) 
and (probably) to prevent women from learning Gemara (see [Rambam Talmud Torah 13,1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Torah_Study.1.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Answer (score 3):

There are two Talmudic passages that utilize the principle of *nashim da'atan kalah*, and the two contexts are somewhat different.

**[Shabbat 33b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=33b&format=pdf)**

> ואמאי קרו ליה ראש המדברים בכל מקום דיתבי רבי יהודה ורבי יוסי ורבי שמעון ויתיב יהודה בן גרים גבייהו פתח ר' יהודה ואמר כמה נאים מעשיהן של אומה זו תקנו שווקים תקנו גשרים תקנו מרחצאות ר' יוסי שתק נענה רשב"י ואמר כל מה שתקנו לא תקנו אלא לצורך עצמן תקנו שווקין להושיב בהן זונות מרחצאות לעדן בהן עצמן גשרים ליטול מהן מכס הלך יהודה בן גרים וסיפר דבריהם ונשמעו למלכות אמרו יהודה שעילה יתעלה יוסי ששתק יגלה לציפורי שמעון שגינה יהרג אזל הוא ובריה טשו בי מדרשא כל יומא הוה מייתי להו דביתהו ריפתא וכוזא דמיא וכרכי כי תקיף גזירתא א"ל לבריה **נשים דעתן קלה עליהן דילמא מצערי לה ומגליא לן** אזלו טשו במערתא
>
> Now, why is he [R. Judah son of R. Ila'i] called the first speaker on all occasions? — For R. Judah, R. Jose, and R. Simeon were sitting, and Judah, a son of proselytes, was sitting near them. R. Judah commenced [the discussion] by observing, 'How fine are the works of this people! They have made streets, they have built bridges, they have erected baths.' R. Jose was silent. R. Simeon b. Yohai answered and said, 'All that they made they made for themselves; they built market-places, to set harlots in them; baths, to rejuvenate themselves; bridges, to levy tolls for them.' Now, Judah the son of proselytes went and related their talk, which reached the government. They decreed: Judah, who exalted [us], shall be exalted, Jose, who was silent, shall be exiled to Sepphoris; Simeon, who censured, let him be executed.
>
> He and his son went and hid themselves in the Beth Hamidrash, [and] his wife brought him bread and a mug of water and they dined.  [But] when the decree became more severe he said to his son, **Women are of unstable temperament: she may be put to the torture and expose us.'**  So they went and hid in a cave. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_33.html#PARTb), my emphasis)

**[Kiddushin 80b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=80b&format=pdf)**

> לא יתייחד אדם עם שתי נשים אבל אשה אחת מתייחדת עם שני אנשים רבי שמעון אומר אף איש אחד מתייחד עם שתי נשים בזמן שאשתו עמו וישן עמהם בפונדקי מפני שאשתו משמרתו מתייחד אדם עם אמו ועם בתו וישן עמהם בקירוב בשר ואם הגדילו זו ישנה בכסותה וזה ישן בכסותו
>
> מ"ט תנא דבי אליהו **הואיל ונשים דעתן קלות עליהן**
>
> MISHNAH. A MAN MAY NOT BE ALONE WITH TWO WOMEN, BUT ONE WOMAN
>   MAY BE ALONE WITH TWO MEN. R. SIMEON SAID: EVEN ONE MAN MAY BE ALONE
>   WITH TWO WOMEN, IF HIS WIFE IS WITH HIM, AND HE MAY SLEEP WITH THEM IN
>   AN INN, BECAUSE HIS WIFE WATCHES HIM. A MAN MAY BE ALONE WITH HIS
>   MOTHER AND HIS DAUGHTER, AND HE MAY SLEEP WITH THEM IN IMMEDIATE
>   BODILY CONTACT; BUT WHEN THEY GROW UP, SHE MUST SLEEP IN HER GARMENT
>   AND HE IN HIS.
>
> GEMARA. What is the reason? — Tanna debe Eliyahu [states]: **Because women are
>   temperamentally light-headed.** ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf), my emphasis)

In the first instance, the phrase is employed to explain that women would be likely to divulge information under torture; in the second instance the phrase is employed to explain why two women cannot be secluded with one man even though one woman can be secluded with two men. In neither case does the Talmud explain whence it derives this principle, e.g. whether it was known via tradition, whether it was the Sages' own observations, etc.

Note, though, that (later interpretations notwithstanding) the Talmud does *not* invoke this principle in its discussion of the permissibility of women studying Torah. In fact, the proof that the Talmud cites for the negative effects of studying Torah does not specify women:

**[Sotah 21b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=21b&format=pdf)**

> אומר בן עזאי חייב אדם ללמד את וכו' ר' אליעזר אומר כל המלמד את בתו תורה מלמדה תיפלות תיפלות ס"ד אלא אימא כאילו למדה תיפלות א"ר אבהו מ"ט דר"א **דכתיב אני חכמה שכנתי ערמה כיון שנכנסה חכמה באדם נכנסה עמו ערמומית** ורבנן האי אני חכמה מאי עבדי ליה מיבעי ליה לכדרבי יוסי בר' חנינא דא"ר יוסי בר' חנינא אין דברי תורה מתקיימין אלא במי שמעמיד עצמו ערום עליהן שנאמר אני חכמה שכנתי ערמה א"ר יוחנן אין דברי תורה מתקיימין אלא במי שמשים עצמו כמי שאינו שנאמר והחכמה מאין תמצא רבי יהושע אומר רוצה אשה וכו' מאי קאמר הכי קאמר רוצה אשה בקב ותיפלות עמו מתשעת קבין ופרישות
>
> HENCE DECLARED BEN AZZAI: A MAN IS UNDER THE OBLIGATION TO TEACH... R. ELIEZER SAYS: WHOEVER TEACHES HIS DAUGHTER TORAH TEACHES HER OBSCENITY. Can it enter your mind [that by teaching her Torah he actually teaches her] obscenity! — Read, rather: as though he had taught her obscenity. R. Abbahu said: What is R. Eliezer's reason? — **Because it is written: I wisdom have made subtilty my dwelling,  i.e., when wisdom enters a man subtilty enters with it.**
>
> And what do the Rabbis  make of the words 'I wisdom'? — They require them in accordance with the teaching of R. Jose son of R. Hanina; for R. Jose son of R. Hanina said: Words of Torah only remain with him who renders himself naked  on their behalf; as it is said: 'I wisdom have made nakedness my dwelling'. R. Johanan said: Words of Torah only remain with him who makes himself like one who is as nothing, as it is said: Wisdom shall be found from nothing.
>
> R. JOSHUA SAYS: A WOMAN PREFERS etc. What does he intend? — He means that a woman prefers one kab and sensuality with it to nine kab with continence. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/sotah/sotah_21.html#PARTb), my emphasis)